# RegGetValue returns type REG_NONE

Tags: visual-c++

I have a method that tries to read a value from the registry at two possible locations. And should return it if successfull. Up until now it worked.

```
wstring Tool::GetCustomizedFromRegistry(LPCWSTR szName)
{
    wstring szProdNameLong = L"";
    HKEY hKey;
    LONG res = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"Software\\Test\\Case", 0, KEY_READ, &hKey);
    if (res == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        DWORD size = 1024;
        WCHAR value[1024];
        DWORD type;
        long error = RegGetValue(hKey, NULL, szName, RRF_RT_REG_SZ, &type, &value, &size);

        if (error == ERROR_SUCCESS && type == RRF_RT_REG_SZ && size > 0)
            return wstring(value);
    }

    res = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"Software\\Test", 0, KEY_READ, &hKey);
    if (res == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        DWORD size = 1024;
        WCHAR value[1024];
        long error = RegGetValue(hKey, NULL, szName, RRF_RT_REG_SZ, NULL, &value, &size);
        if (error == ERROR_SUCCESS)
            return wstring(value);
    }

    return L"";
}
```

Since updating one of our development machines to Windows 10 this no longer works. The problem is that we check the type return value of `RegGetValue`. That is `REG_NONE` instead of `REG_SZ` (in the registry it is actually `REG_SZ`).

Comment: The documentation for RegGetValue says about parameter two `lpSubKey The name of the registry key. This key must be a subkey of the key specified by the hkey parameter.` I don't see a note that `NULL` is allowed for `lpSubKey`.

Comment: Thanks, that tip helped me to find the actuall error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem was I used the wrong constant. I used `RRF_RT_REG_SZ` which has a value of 2 and `RRF_RT_REG_NONE` has the value of one. 1 will be returned in the type variable.

I should have used the constant `REG_SZ` which is actually 1. So the method returned the value correctly but I compared it to the wrong constant.

I don't know why it had ever worked.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code on windows 10 and it working fine. Please take care that if you are running x86 application on x64 machine the keys will be at "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node", the keys in "Software\Test\Case" can only be accessed if your application is X64.